# Trying to instantiate PdfReader, but am getting runtime error, "Cannot create an instance of the static class PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader"

Tags: c#, wpf, pdfsharp

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader();
```

I'm getting that error on PdfReader. It's a WPF project and I originally tried the PdfSharp-Wpf.dll, but I also tried the PdfSharp.dll. Both are getting this  error.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PdfReader is a static class which can't be instantiated. You want to do:

```
PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(@"/path/to/file.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel silly because I know what static classes are. But I saw an example online that was setting it up like that, so I just assumed it was right. Maybe that was from an older version of the library.